# Javascript grid with css position

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have one big problem. I try to create a slots and create a grid from this slots. I do it in this way:

I have class Slot.js i draw there just a simple rectangle. 
Now I make a grid in class Main:

```
for(let i = 0; i <= ROW_NUM; i++)
{
    for(let j=0; j <= COL_NUM; j++)
    {
        let s = new Slot();
        let gStyle = s.graph.style;
        gStyle.left = j * SLOT_WIDTH + "px";
        gStyle.top = i * SLOT_HEIGHT + "px";
        gStyle.position = "absolute";
        g.appendChild(s.graph);


    }
}
```

So I have some div g and add to this div my slots. Now I want to set position to this div to center. But if I set this in my style.css file, this div dont set correct place. The grid position is always start from the left top corner. If I set absolute position then this div will change his position.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Simply add class to center a absolute div.

HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="centered-div">
    Hi i'm centered
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#parent { position: relative; }
.centered-div { position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%,-50%) }
```

No JS needed

Comment: You mean I should delete positioning in js? ( gStyle.left = j * SLOT_WIDTH + "px"; If I do this then from what web browser know that there should be 50 columns and 50 rows?;]  If I delete JS positioning, then grid looks like this: [LINK](https://gyazo.com/11f58f5d7d3854aba8c74bc877e58820) If I dont delete positioning in JS i get this: [LINK](https://gyazo.com/2f35f029e6bb55f18f6c2b7f8a8402f4) It`s better but wrong position, (not center just something like text-align: right).

Comment: Ok I resolve this problem. in my css file i have: [code] #grid{ position: relative; left: 0; right: 0; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; }[/code] In my js script I added [code] let g = document.getElementById("grid"); g.style.width = COL_NUMS * SLOT_WIDTH + "px"; [/code]                                     In other words I just set the width of the grid in pixels.